# Почему ВК не то время возвращает?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, время

В `message` я получаю время и беру час:

```
int hour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(new Date(vk_time * 1000L));
```

Но проблема в том, что час неправильный (на телефоне на 4 часа меньше).

P. S.: В настройках телефона время настроено вручную, если переключиться на "Дата и время сети", то становится на 4 часа меньше.

Comment: ВК возвращает время в UTC

Comment: @andreymal, значит нужно ... ? Что?

Comment: @Flippy добавить количество часов в соответствии с вашим часовым поясом.

Comment: Джавы я не знаю и что нужно тоже не знаю) Но попробую предположить, что `Date` никак не работает с часовыми поясами и переводить UTC в нужный вам часовой пояс надо как-то самостоятельно

Comment: @insolor плохое решение, количество часов в часовом поясе имеет свойство меняться в зависимости от даты (вспоминаем октябрь 2014-го)

Comment: @andreymal ну так надо определить разницу с UTC программно и её добавлять, тогда корректно по идее будет работать.

Comment: @insolor тоже неа, если для примера взять московский часовой пояс, то для UTC-времени до октября 2014-го нужно прибавлять четыре часа, а после — уже три часа. 1414270800 — это 2014-10-26 01:00, однако 1414274400 — это ТОЖЕ 2014-10-26 01:00!  А ещё где-то там летнее время когда-то было :D

Comment: Ты на эмуляторе запускаешь приложение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Беру час в `UTC` и без

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
   int user_hour = Integer.parseInt(sdf.fotmat(new Date)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   int utc_hour = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(new Date()));
   ```
2. Разницу между ними прибавляем к часам сервера

   ```
   server_hour += user_hour - utc_hour
   ```